# How to send json data to RESTful API in Unity3D?

Tags: php, json, rest, unity-game-engine

Good afternoon friends!

I am a programmer and I'm a little time learning about the Unity and the game development universe. I came a doubt that I could not find the answer very well.
What is the best architecture or solution to work with a mobile multiplayer game using a restful webservice? It's possible? It is the best way to do something online multiplayer?

I've been studying a bit WWWForm class and tried to simulate sending data via JSON using JSONObject but without much success. I can not actually send a javascript object.

An example:

```
public void enviar(JSONObject json, Objeto obj)
{
    string url = "http://myurl/unity.php";

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

    form.AddField("var1", "[{\"Nome\":\""+obj.name+"\"}]");

    WWW www = new WWW(url, form);

    StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));
}

IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;

        // check for errors
    if(www.error == null)
    {
        Debug.Log("WWW Ok!: " + www.text);
    } else {
        Debug.Log("WWW Error: "+ www.error);
    }    
}
```

and my PHP file I have the following test:

```
$t = $_POST['var1'];
$novot = json_decode($t);

foreach ($novot as $novo){
$fp = fopen("bloco1.txt", "a");

$escreve = fwrite($fp, $novo);

fclose($fp);
}
```

All I can back is a stdClass, I can handle, but that to me is something very manual. There is no simple and correct way of working with webservices?

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how send more more rich / structured data back and forth?  Yes, JSON would be an obvious choice.

**REST API's** are simple, client-server, stateless. etc.  Typical web paradigm.  There are some frameworks that can help with authentication and wrapping object-oriented code to expose it as a service.  Many of these fall into the 'mirco framework' category.  [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) for example.  [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/) has some related classes too.  Zend also has a standalone offering called [pigility](https://apigility.org/) - not suggesting you purchase it but it could give you some ideas.

I'd search Git Hub for "rest server" or similar.

Also if you are not writing good OOP code you will continue to find things "very manual".  The [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (Don't Repeat Yourself) principal is a good one to adhere to when starting out.

Best of luck.  Been having fun myself with Unity3d of late teaching my little brother some coding skills.

Comment: I know what is web service. The problem is how to use this with Unity stressing all the problems I mentioned in the previous post, @ficuscr, haha. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe ask more specific questions then as opposed to "How to simply and correctly use a web service"... Not sure how to help you.  I'd encourage you to look at other game developers source code.

Answer (score 0):

Unity doesn't have the best built in WebServices, but developers have built a lot of plugins that are on the [Asset Store.](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/) Additionally, I use the [BestHTTP](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10872) plugin, and absolutely love it! (although it does cost money).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Michael. I looked but I was not sure if that package helped only if the API was in ASP .NET. In any case, I think that the best solution can not be even connect via a web service but something like the Photon. I'm still studying it and even to a little lost.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I must have missed that you were using this for multiplayer. Photon is a good system. Also, Unity finally released their new multiplayer components/setup in [Unity 5.1](http://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/unity-5.1)